# Filter items in an array within an object array

Tags: javascript

I'm looking to filter an array of objects that is within an array of objects. E.g. items within the nested array are filtered out but not items of the outer most array.

Here is a sample input array:

```
categories = [{
  categoryName: 'Mammals',
  items: [{
    name: 'Dog',
    power: '52',
  },{
    name: 'Bear',
    power: '205',
  },{
    name: 'Mouse',
    power: '7',
  }]
},{
  categoryName: 'Reptiles',
  items: [{
    name: 'Alligator',
    power: '230',
  },{
    name: 'Turtle',
    power: '39',
  }]
}];
```

Desired output: items with power greater than 50:

```
output = [{
  categoryName: 'Mammals',
  items: [{
    name: 'Dog',
    power: '52',
  },{
    name: 'Bear',
    power: '205',
  }]
},{
  categoryName: 'Reptiles',
  items: [{
    name: 'Alligator',
    power: '230',
  }]
}];
```

Here is the code that I tried:

```js
let categories = [{
  categoryName: 'Mammals',
  items: [{
    name: 'Dog',
    power: '52',
  },{
    name: 'Bear',
    power: '205',
  },{
    name: 'Mouse',
    power: '7',
  }]
},{
  categoryName: 'Reptiles',
  items: [{
    name: 'Alligator',
    power: '230',
  },{
    name: 'Turtle',
    power: '39',
  }]
}];

let output = categories.filter((category) => category.items.power > 50);
console.log(output);
```

I also tried using the `some` function like this:

```
output = categories.filter((category) => category.items.some((item) => item.power > 50))
```

And still did not get the desired results. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Write a function using `filter` that works on just one category, then `map` it across the array of all categories.

Comment: Looks like your numeric values are being stored as strings, for which `>` comparison behaves unintuitively. You might need to do something like `categories.filter((category) => parseInt(category.items.power) > 50)`

Comment: @Hamms: In its endless intuitive convenience, JavaScript actually does a numeric comparison when comparing a number to a string with `>`. But yeah, being explicit is good advice.

Comment: Oh, hah, so it does! I think I was thinking about the comparing strings to strings case. Thanks for the correction!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `map()` to iterate over the categories, then use `filter()` to filter the items in each category.

```
output = categories.map(cat => ({
    ...cat, 
    items: cat.items.filter(i => i.power > 50)
}))
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `map` and `filter`:

```js
let categories = [
  {
    categoryName: 'Mammals',
    items: [{
        name: 'Dog',
        power: '52',
      }, {
        name: 'Bear',
        power: '205',
      }, {
        name: 'Mouse',
        power: '7',
    }]
  }, 
  {
    categoryName: 'Reptiles',
    items: [{
        name: 'Alligator',
        power: '230',
      }, {
        name: 'Turtle',
        power: '39',
    }]
  }
];

let output = categories.map((category) => {
   let categoryName = category.categoryName;
   let items = category.items.filter((category) => category.power > 50);
   return {categoryName, items};
});

console.log(output);
```

Comment: Perhaps change "name" to "categoryName" per the OP desired output

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss Correct. Thanks for pointing, I missed that. Updated the code.